# Is No issues and No problem same? If not, Which is better to use based on context?

Tags: phrase-usage, spoken-english, informal-language

I've seen people use no issues and no problem for the same set of question.
Which of the following is better or there is anything wrong with using it.

Example:-

Person1: I would be late for the meeting.
Person2:- No issues, you may join later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're exactly the same in meaning. 'No problem' might have been in common use for longer than 'No issues'. A while back people started using the word 'issue' in place of the word 'problem', presumably because the word 'problem' had negative connotations.

That being said, I would recommend using the phrase, 'You're welcome' when someone says 'Thank you' in a formal situation, instead of either one of these. They are informal slang and they assume that the person you're responding to thinks they've caused you some trouble, which might or might not be true. They could be considered sloppy or disrespectful in a formal conversation.

Comment: Even more informal: "No worries." This used to be distinctively Australian, but I'm hearing it more frequently in North America these days.

Comment: I find it really tedious when I thank someone and they say "no problem". I don't mind so much if they say "it was no trouble". Dwilli is right about the informality of "no problem/no issue".